# No DNS record or entry in Host file, but can still access IIS site?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, iis, vpn, virtual-machines

We have a VM in azure (with no Public IP), that has a bunch of sites inside the IIS. These sites are only accessible from inside the VM or whilst being connected to our OpenVPN. There is no DNS record for these sites, and there is also nothing in the system's host file. For the life of me I can not figure out how this works. I have set up a new VM, and am trying to get it to work the same way this VM does; but I am truly stuck and can't figure it out. Any ideas would be most appreciated!

-Tried putting the private ip and site name in the Host file. This has worked within the VM, but not when connecting to the OpenVPN.

-Tried turning off the firewall to see if we could then access the site with the VPN. No luck

-Tried putting in the Private IP in the allowed list for port 443 of the VPN.

-Tried putting the subnet of the new VM into the allowed list of the VPN, and the other VM is in a different subnet (within the same VNet).

EDIT: To clarify, I have 2 issues. 1st I really can't see how the pervious employee set this up. As far as I am aware you have to either have a DNS entry or a host file entry, and there is neither. 2nd, I can't seem to open the site, when I have the VPN turned on.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you clarify? Is the problem that the VPN clients cannot access the site by name? Or is it that they can access the site by name and you don't know why that is?

Comment: Hi Joeqwerty. To clarify, I have 2 issues. 1st I really can't see how the pervious employee set this up. As far as I am aware you have to either have a DNS entry or a host file entry, and there is neither. 2nd, I can't seem to open the site, when I have the VPN turned on.

Comment: Is the name you are connecting to single label or fully qualified? If you ping the name, does it resolve? To what? Using what name resolution? DNS? Netbios? LLMNR?

Comment: Could it be in your local DNS? Look at your local hardware firewall / router to see if there is a DNS entry for the existing sites in there - it will be acting as your DNS forwarder and could easily have a few defined names in there..

Comment: `As far as I am aware you have to either have a DNS entry or a host file entry,` Windows has multiple types of name resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It was a DNS Manager in a random VM... Sorry to waste everyone time lol